# How can i clone my private repositories inside GitHub Actions, without using the checkout action?

Tags: github

I have many dependencies for other private repositories. We have a site builder and each repository is a module. Sometimes a website that has 50 modules needs to clone 50 private repos.

I already do it using the checkout action. But checkout action is extremely verbose and it increases our action time. I would prefer to somehow clone them using the git command inside the runner.

How can I do that in a secure, safe manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Save your SSH key as a secret in GitHub.
2. Execute a bash script inside a runner that accesses the private key and clones the repo.

Comment: Do you mean that I should copy/paste my private SSH key from GitHub Action secrets and paste it inside the ~/.ssh/ directory? Would that work?

Comment: @MohammadMiras not necessarily. The point is that you can access ssh key from GitHub Actions runner, and after that you can use it to clone a private repo. I will update the answer with a code sample once I get my laptop.

Comment: Thank you ,  I am waiting for your sample code